# How do I move an activity indicator?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, swift3

I am trying to place a activity indicator next to my button after it is pressed. All I see for placement it .center, is there anyway to move the indicator to a custom position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simply set the `origin` property of `frame` for your  `ActivityIndicator` according to your `Button`.

```
activityIndicator.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: , y: )//Set the origin related to your button
```